# How to immutable update an object given that we have to pass the same object as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, mutable

I have an object `amounts` that gets updated on button clicks. Ans i pass that object as a prop to another component. What i am doing right now is updating object in mutable way on button click event.

```
onClick = e => {
  amounts.map(
      amount => (amount.tax = taxes ? 500 : 0)
  );
}

<Display amounts={amounts} />
```

How can i update amounts in an immutable way?

Comment: Is amounts an array of numbers? Also, you're calling the mapped value `option` but then you're using it as `amount` - is that a typo or intentional?

Comment: it is an array of objects and that was a typo, i will correct that

Comment: `amounts.map` creates new array that is not used in any way. You actually need to assign it to have an effect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I got your point. However, since amounts is an array of objects, it was getting updated directly. But, to achieve immutability, is this a correct solution const `xyz = amounts.map(.....)` and then `amounts = xyz`

Comment: Also, is `onClick` part of the same component that renders `<Display />`?

Comment: Im amazed that you say you are updating the object in mutable way, yet...where is the update? And `=` should be `===`. And `.map` returns a new array. And for the `Display` to see the changes (for the changes to have effect`) you need to update the state

Comment: yes, onClick is the part of <Display />

Comment: It will be = and not === as taxes is a boolean.

Comment: no, you cant achieve immutability through this in JS. you will have to deepclone the object first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are a few things going on:

1. You are not updating the `amounts` Array reference, so React will not re-render based on this mutation.
2. You are using `Array#map` to update a single property. This **will** update the Object reference in the amounts collection.
3. There is no `setAmounts` or anything similar in order to update the value of the `amount` property in a parent component.

Assuming you are using `useState` in the `<Display />`s parent component, you will have to pass the `setAmounts` function to the `<Display />` component using props.

```
<Display amounts={amounts} setAmounts={setAmounts} />
```

```
onClick = e => {
  setAmounts(
    amounts.map(
      amount => ({ ...amount, tax: taxes ? 500 : 0 })
    );
  );
}
```